# Why is my useState value not updated when it is referenced from inside a function that runs on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mouseclick-event

I have a state value for all the users in the project I am working on, and the state value is updated as I expect it to. The problem is when I try to reference the 'users' state from inside a function, I get the previous value of the state.

I thought it was just because useState updated asynchronously but I am getting the expected value when I reference the 'users' state from other parts of the app. I also tried putting the function inside a useEffect hook that runs every time the 'users' state runs but I still had no luck. The function in question runs with a click event.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscribe = onSnapshot( usersRef, snap => {
      let tempUsers = []
      snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
        tempUsers.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
      setUsers(tempUsers)
    })

    return () => {
      subscribe()
    }
  }, [] )

useEffect(() => { 
    const followBtn = document.querySelector('.follow-btn')
    console.log(users.find(person => person.id === 'uekUbQRcBRYiZpipQGhHUtjwNDA3'))
    console.log(users)
  
    const handleFollow = async () => {
      console.log(users.find(person => person.id === 'uekUbQRcBRYiZpipQGhHUtjwNDA3'))
      console.log(users)
    }

    followBtn.addEventListener('click', handleFollow)

    return () => {
      followBtn.removeEventListener('click', handleFollow)
    }
  }, [users])
```

**the users array in the two above console logs are different, the one outside the function gives the expected value but the one inside the function gives the outdated value, and I am not altering it. The data is being pulled from firebase.**

Comment: In the code you've shown there is no `users` array outside of a function ;-) Honestly: Could you please make that up into an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that all the necessary details are available?

Comment: It looks like you're creating a closure over an earlier state. But why are you using direct DOM manipulation? You'll need to show more code if you want help, there is nothing in the included portion that in any way updates the state.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: @pilchard I have updated the provided code, and I used direct DOM manipulation because I put the function inside a useEffect hook and therefore I could not access it from the 'follow btn'. I had to use an event listener.

Comment: @David I have updated the code, do you need more information ?

Comment: Please post more of your code you didn't show the whole second useEffect so we can't even see if you've set up your dependency array correctly

Comment: @Dominic yeah sorry, I just did that.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your click event logic to your button `onClick` event:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const subscribe = onSnapshot( usersRef, snap => {

    setUsers(() => snap.docs.map(doc => {
      return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
    }))
  })

  return () => subscribe()
}, [] )

useEffect(() => { 
  console.log('users changed', users)
  console.log(users.find(person => person.id === 'uekUbQRcBRYiZpipQGhHUtjwNDA3'))
}, [users])

const handleFollow = async () => {
  console.log('button click', users)
  console.log(users.find(person => person.id === 'uekUbQRcBRYiZpipQGhHUtjwNDA3'))
}

return (
  <button 
    onClick={handleFollow}
  >
    click me
  </button>
)
```

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: I don't know how is the rest of your code, but [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-khcynl?file=/demo.tsx) is a little example of how you should use `useState` and `useEffect` and it's working fine here.